# Authenticating to GCP Using Terraform Cloud and Google Provider

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have the below code for provisioning a GCS bucket in my GCP project

I am using Terraform Cloud and i have authenticated using Application Default credentials to GCP
I have created an env variable in TF Cloud with the below values :

GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEYFILE_JSON = "C:\Users\palla\Downloads\strange-flame-167811-26139c8660b2.json"

My Terraform Code is provided below :

```
provider "google" {
  project     = "strange-flame-167811"
  region      = "us-east1"
  credentials = "C:\Users\palla\Downloads\strange-flame-167811-26139c8660b2.json"
}


resource "google_storage_bucket" "test" {
  name     = "my-project-id-test-bucket"
  location = "us-east1"
}
```

When i run Terraform plan i get these errors below:

```
The Terraform configuration must be valid before initialization so that
Terraform can determine which modules and providers need to be installed.
╷
│ Error: Invalid escape sequence
│ 
│   on main.tf line 4, in provider "google":
│    4:   credentials = "C:\Users\palla\Downloads\strange-flame-167811-26139c8660b2.json"
│ 
│ The \U escape sequence must be followed by eight hexadecimal digits.
╵

╷
│ Error: Invalid escape sequence
│ 
│   on main.tf line 4, in provider "google":
│    4:   credentials = "C:\Users\palla\Downloads\strange-flame-167811-26139c8660b2.json"
│ 
│ The symbol "p" is not a valid escape sequence selector.
╵

╷
│ Error: Invalid escape sequence
│ 
│   on main.tf line 4, in provider "google":
│    4:   credentials = "C:\Users\palla\Downloads\strange-flame-167811-26139c8660b2.json"
│ 
│ The symbol "D" is not a valid escape sequence selector.
╵

╷
│ Error: Invalid escape sequence
│ 
│   on main.tf line 4, in provider "google":
│    4:   credentials = "C:\Users\palla\Downloads\strange-flame-167811-26139c8660b2.json"
│ 
│ The symbol "s" is not a valid escape sequence selector.
```

Comment: Have you tried using forward slashes instead (/)?

Comment: I would use Terraform Cloud Variables instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call out the credentials as a file:
credentials = file(".json")

Comment: If i do this , i get this error *********Error: Invalid function argument
on main.tf line 13, in provider "google":
  credentials = file("C:\\strange-flame-167811-26139c8660b2.json")
while calling file(path)
Invalid value for "path" parameter: no file exists at "C:\\strange-flame-167811-26139c8660b2.json"; this function works only with files that are distributed as part of the configuration source code, so if this file will be created by a resource in this configuration you must instead obtain this result from an attribute of that resource. *****The .json file is in C drive just under C

Comment: I am using Terraform Cloud just to let you know. So don' t think this kind of file referencing will work. I have to add the credential as an Env or TF Var and use it only

Comment: This has worked for me, now I was deploying in GCP using Terraform in Linux environment like this:
credentials = file("/home/rnicholl_netapp_com/terraform/tlv-support-rn-terra.json")

Comment: I wonder if the file is in the same directory where you are running your terraform commands if you can just do "./file.json"

Comment: I am not running any terraform command. All i am doing is using VCS driven workflow with Terraform Cloud. So when i make changes locally in VS code and push to Github, it automatically triggers a plan. It throws error that time. Was your use case same as mine or you were using Terraform locally that it worked for you

Comment: I was using it locally.

Answer (score 0):

Since the backslash (`\`) is an escape character in Terraform, you need to escape it by prepending another backslash.

> `\\` Literal backslash

Change path to: `credentials = "C:\\Users\\xxx\\Downloads\\credentials.json"`

See: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/strings#escape-sequences

Comment: After changing the path to the format --> credentials = "C:\\Users\\palla\\Downloads\\strange-flame-167811-26139c8660b2.json", i get the error: Error: JSON credentials are not valid: invalid character 'C' looking for beginning of value